# Fast binary search on text column in SQLite

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have a table with about 80000 rows. I need to do searches like: `SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'abc%'`. The wildcard is always at the end. Even with an index, it's too slow on Android. How can I make it faster? Can sqlite be forced to internally perform binary search on the text column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A normal index does not order the entries case-insensitively, which would be required for `LIKE`.

To allow the [LIKE optimization](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#like_opt) to work, you need a `NOCASE` index:

```
> CREATE TABLE names(name TEXT);
> CREATE INDEX i1 ON names(name);
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'abc%';
SCAN TABLE names USING COVERING INDEX i1 (~500000 rows)
> CREATE INDEX i2 ON names(name COLLATE NOCASE);
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE 'abc%';
SEARCH TABLE names USING COVERING INDEX i2 (name>? AND name<?) (~31250 rows)
```

If you'd want a case-sensitive search, you could use `GLOB` instead:

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM names WHERE name GLOB 'abc*';
SEARCH TABLE names USING COVERING INDEX i1 (name>? AND name<?) (~31250 rows)
```